# ANT_HOME Path. what to set when installed using apt-get install

Tags: ubuntu, ant

Forgive me for the superfluous questions, but i have been thinking about it for some time now.

I wanted to install "ant" on my local machine today so I did a normal

```
   sudo apt-get install ant
```

it worked like a charm!

```
   ant -version
```

the above command spitted out the following .

```
   Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 14 2013
```

the command

```
    ant
```

gave me the following output

```
  Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
  Build failed
```

Now I wanted to setup ANT_HOME environment variable  in my ~/.bashrc file. which got me the my query.

1) I am not sure what path to use , initially I was under the impression that sudo apt-get install xyz installs the software in /usr/bin directory but then when I browsed through the directory it was not there instead I found ant folder sitting in /usr/bin/shared directory.
I wanted to know if my knowledge is incorrect about the /usr/bin directory.

2) I wanted to know how to see the installation path or the root directory of the software installed in ubuntu 13.10

I want to learn and I was hoping you guys could help me out !! :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`which ant` will give you the absolute path to any executable accessible in your `$PATH`, ie:

`jonny$ which java
/usr/bin/java`

As for why you want to set your `ANT_HOME` environment variable - I don't think that's going to help with the missing `build.xml` error you encountered - that's ANT's way of telling you it expects to find your build script in the current working directory.  If you want to point ANT to another `build.xml` file, you can use the `-f` switch, ie:

`ant -f ~/Projects/foo/build.xml`

Answer (score 0):

either you first switch to project directory or give a link to your project directory in order to execute ant.ant looks for build.xml file